# How do I make my 2nd div go to edge of page if the previous div's height varies?

Tags: css

I know how to get the first div to go to the edge of the page using position: absolute; but I don't know how to get subsequent divs to go to the edge since the height of the div above it will vary based on how wide the user's browser is.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: #333; height: 200px; width: 100%;">
  This div is exactly 200px tall, so I know that the position top value of my next div is going to be 200px.
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 0px; background-color: #FBD2D7; width: 100%; padding: 50px; font-size: 2vw;">
  I only want this section to be as tall as it needs to be to fit the text. Where it ends will vary based on how wide the viewer's browser is.
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; background-color: #93B6C7; height: 200px; width: 100%;">
  I don't know how to position this div because where the previous div ends will vary.
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow! Just editing my answer now because you went ahead and added code, which initially I was complaining about!

Here's a solution that looks similar to the code you've provided. The key is to put all three divs within a single, absolutely positioned div.

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  right:0px;
  left: 140px;
}

#variable {
  background: lightblue;
}

.set {
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="set"></div>
<div id="variable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nisl ligula, tempor vitae porttitor vel, ornare at dolor. Cras faucibus metus eget risus efficitur fermentum. Praesent laoreet sodales elementum. Maecenas dapibus elit urna, eget eleifend mauris ultricies at. Mauris sed risus ut est accumsan maximus sit amet ut augue. Quisque dapibus nisi ut mi semper porttitor. Praesent id venenatis lectus. Etiam nec facilisis metus.</div>
<div class="set"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about the code. I pasted it in, but didn't see how to block it off until after I posted. :) :) (:

Answer (score 0):

You can give them a parent and position that, than all the children will just flow normally

```html
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
  <div style="background-color: #333; height: 200px; width: 100%;">This div is exactly 200px tall, so I know that the position top value of my next div is going to be 200px.</div>

  <div style="background-color: #FBD2D7; width: 100%; padding: 50px; font-size: 2vw;">I only want this section to be as tall as it needs to be to fit the text. Where it ends will vary based on how wide the viewer's browser is.</div>

  <div style="background-color: #93B6C7; height: 200px; width: 100%;">I don't know how to position this div because where the previous div ends will vary.</div>
</div>
```